JSON deserialize in POST endpoint
I know I'm probably doing something stupid, but I can't see it. I'm trying to deserialize this JSON:
{
  "SendFields": 
  {
    "Category": 
    {
      "value": "Request Something"
    },
    "email": 
    {
      "value": "someone@somplace.com"
    }
  }
}

With this class structure:
public class SendFields
{
    [JsonProperty("Category")]
    public KeyValuePair<string, string> Category { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public KeyValuePair<string, string> email { get; set; }

}
public class MyData
{
    [JsonProperty("SendFields")]
    public KeyValuePair<string,SendFields> SendFields { get; set; }
}

But I keep getting nulls in my SendFields KVP:

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but maybe someone here can point me to my obvious blindness.  :)

public class MyData {     public SendFields SendFields { get; set; } }

The way you have it set up currently to deserialize from json you'd need to have your json set up similar to this, each KVP property is string/string, so you need a key, and a value for each kvp property.
{
  "SendFields": {
    "Category": {
      "key": "category1",
      "value": "Request Something"
    },
    "email": {
      "key": "email1",
      "value": "someone@somplace.com"
    }
  }
}


Unfortunately, I'm getting this json from another application, not mine.  So I'm trying to make my class structure match what they are sending.

if you can't change the json structure. use this site https://json2csharp.com/ and paste your json data in there and it will generate the C# data structure for you.
the root issue is that the KVP data type wont work for the supplied json data, but by using that site you'll see that you can create  a Category and email Class with value properties that will match your json data.

Using that json2csharp.com site worked like a charm!  Thanks for the help!

The matching structure can look like:
public class MyData
{
    public SendFields SendFields { get; set; }
}

public class SendFields
{
    public ValueHolder Category { get; set; }
    public ValueHolder email { get; set; }
}

public class ValueHolder
{
    public string value { get; set; }
}

Notes:

There is convention for mapping Dictionary<,> to JSON object (supported by both System.Text.Json and Newtonsoft's Json.NET) which is used for "dynamic" property names (for example you can substitute SendFields with Dictionary<string, ValueHolder>), but not for KeyValuePair<,>, AFAIK.

I would recommend to name properties using standard conventions (i.e. Pascal case) and mark them with appropriate attributes (for Newtonsoft's Json.NET - JsonProperty and for System.Text.Json - JsonPropertyName).

With original SendFields the following will work for Newtonsoft's Json.NET), but not for System.Text.Json with default settings:
public class MyData
{
    [JsonProperty("SendFields")]
    public SendFields SendFields { get; set; }
}

Though I still would recommend against using KeyValuePair<,> here since it does not correctly represent your JSON structure

Consider using online tools like https://quicktype.io/csharp or https://json2csharp.com/ to generate models for your JSON.


